# How to get my ideal result and let input disappear?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I found some code to solve binary tree question.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Tree {
    int number;
    struct Tree* parent;
    struct Tree* left;
    struct Tree* right;
}tree;

int n;
int temp;

tree* root; //root

void insert(int);
void preorder(tree*);

int main(void) {
    //readin
    while(scanf("%d", &n) != EOF) {
        root = NULL;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            insert(temp);
        }
        preorder(root);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void insert(int num) {
    tree* empty = (tree*)(malloc(1 * sizeof(tree)));
    if(root == NULL) {  //set as root
        root = empty;
        root->number = num;
        root->parent = NULL;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
    tree* here = root;
    
    //insert
    int stop = 0;
    while(!stop) {
        if(num > here->number) {    //bigger
            if(here->right == NULL) {   //insert here
                here->right = empty;
                empty->number = num;
                empty->parent = here;
                empty->left = NULL;
                empty->right = NULL;
                stop = 1;
            } else {    //go right
                here = here->right;
            }
        } else {    //smaller
            if(here->left == NULL) {    //insert here
                here->left = empty;
                empty->number = num;
                empty->parent = here;
                empty->left = NULL;
                empty->right = NULL;
                stop = 1;
            } else {
                here = here->left;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return ;
}

void preorder(tree* node) { //mid left right
    if(node == NULL)
        return ;
    printf("%d ", node->number);
    if(node->left != NULL) {    //go left
        preorder(node->left);
    }
    if(node->right != NULL) {   //go right
        preorder(node->right);
    }
    
    return ;
}
```

When I run code, I found a problem.

Code result：

[image]

The input should disappear but it didn't.

What I expected input:

```
11
368 115 121 88 741 762 801 34 41 511 60
6
5 2 10 4 9 15
```

What I expected output:

```
368 115 88 34 41 60 121 741 511 762 801
5 2 4 10 9 15
```

What should I do to let input disappear?
How to get my ideal result?
The output was Binary Tree Traversal's Preorder Traversal.

Comment: If you want the input and output to be separate, then you need a loop that creates multiple trees, followed by a loop that outputs those trees. Your code has a loop that inputs one tree, and outputs that tree, and then repeats.

Comment: You could always put your input into a file, and then re-direct it as input.  E.g.: `./tree_program < number_lists.txt`

Comment: Your `insert()` doesn't return after creating the root node, it continues to add the new node to the left of root a second time. Walk through the code on paper, drawing the tree out as it goes.  Luckily the `insert()` then NULLs the child pointers, which repairs the error.